Socket.io disconnecting with error "transport close"
io as my socket provider, for a android project.
Server is in NodeJs and client is in Kotlin androdid.
in my socket operation Small emitting with Json is working fine. but while im tryning to send file like 20Mb in base64 , its disconnecting the client by the error "transport close".
in the same way in Base64 im sandeing file size : 1Mb, 2Mb 3Mb is working fine. in my server i have increased the maxHttpBUffer to 100Mb , but still same , please help me.
Below is my server Code
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server, {
  maxHttpBufferSize: 10E7, //100 MB
  pingTimeout: 1000*60,
  pingInterval: 60000 // Increase the ping interval to 25 seconds
});

const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const CHUNK_DIR = path.join(__dirname, "chunks");
const FILE_DIR = path.join(__dirname, "files");

if (!fs.existsSync(CHUNK_DIR)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(CHUNK_DIR);
}
if (!fs.existsSync(FILE_DIR)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(FILE_DIR);
}

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("a user connected");

  socket.on('disconnect', function(reason) {
    console.log("disconnect-", reason)});

  socket.on("chat message", (msg, callback) => {
    console.log("new msg->");

    console.log("rec", msg["reciver"]);

    //io.emit(msg.reciver, msg.data);

    io.timeout(1500).emit(msg.reciver, msg.data, (err, response) => {
      if (response.length < 1) {
        callback({
          status: "not recived",
        });
        console.log("not Acknowledge", response);
      } else {
        callback({
          status: "ok",
        });
        console.log(response[0]);
      }
    });
  });

  socket.on("media message", (msg, callback) => {
    console.log("new msg->");

    console.log("rec", msg["reciver"]);

    //io.emit(msg.reciver, msg.data);

    io.emit(msg.reciver, msg.data, (err, response) => {
      if (response.length < 1) {
        callback({
          status: "not recived",
        });
        console.log("not Acknowledge", response);
      } else {
        callback({
          status: "ok",
        });
        console.log(response[0]);
      }
    });
  });


  socket.on('file-chunk', (res) => {
    const { chunk, index, totalChunks, fileName,id,reciver,data } = res;
    const chunkPath = path.join(CHUNK_DIR, `${fileName}.part${index}`);
    const chunkBuffer = Buffer.from(chunk, 'base64'); // Decoding base64 string to buffer

    fs.writeFile(chunkPath, chunkBuffer, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Error writing chunk:", err);
            
        } else {
            console.log(`Chunk ${index + 1}/${totalChunks} received`);

            if (index === totalChunks - 1) {
                const finalPath = path.join(FILE_DIR, fileName);


                if (!fs.existsSync(finalPath)) {
                  try {
                      fs.writeFileSync(finalPath, '', { encoding: 'base64' });
                      console.log("File created:", finalPath);
                  } catch (error) {
                      console.error("Error creating file:", error);
                      // Handle error if file creation fails
                      return;
                  }
              }



                const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(finalPath);

                for (let i = 0; i < totalChunks; i++) {
                    const chunkPath = path.join(CHUNK_DIR, `${fileName}.part${i}`);
                    const chunk = fs.readFileSync(chunkPath);
                    writeStream.write(chunk);
                    fs.unlinkSync(chunkPath); // Remove chunk after writing
                }

                writeStream.end();
                console.log('File transfer complete:', finalPath);

                // Emit the file back to the client
                fs.readFile(finalPath, { encoding: 'base64' }, (err, fileData) => {
                  if (err) {
                      console.error("Error reading file:", err);
                  } else {
                      if (fileData.length === 0) {
                          console.error("File data is empty.");
                      } else {
                          //console.log("File data:", fileData);
                          io.emit(reciver, { fileName, fileData,data });
                      }
                  }
              });
              
            }
        }
    });
  });

  socket.on('file-chunk1', (res) => {
    const { fileName, reciver, data, fileData } = res;
    console.log("data recived",reciver)
    io.emit(reciver, { fileName, fileData, data });
});

 
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("listening on *:3000");
});


**Belo is my code for client **

class LiveMessage internal constructor(socket: Socket) {


    private lateinit var messarepository: Chatepository
    private lateinit var threadRepository: Thread_repository
    private lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository
    private lateinit var encripter: Encripter
    private var showNotification: ShowNotification? = null


    companion object {
        var mSocket: Socket? = null
        val json = Gson()
        fun sendMessage(chats: Chats, reciver: String?) {

            val customMessage = CustomMessage(reciver, Data("live android", chats))
            val jsondta = json.toJson(customMessage, CustomMessage::class.java)
            mSocket?.emit("chat message", JSONObject(jsondta), object : Ack {
                override fun call(vararg args: Any?) {
                    args?.let {
                        try {
                            val callback = it.get(0);
                            val obj = JSONObject(callback.toString())

                            if (obj.getString("status") != "ok") {/* Toast.makeText(
                                     com.easy.easysent.Helper.Application.application,
                                     "socket Error",
                                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                 ).show();*/
                            }

                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            e.printStackTrace()
                        }


                    }
                }

            })
        }


        fun sendFile(filePath: String, reciver: String,chats: Chats) {
            val file = File(filePath)
            val chunkSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024 // 5MB
            val totalChunks = (file.length() / chunkSize).toInt() + 1



            Thread {

                val customMessage = Data("live android", chats)
                val jsondta = json.toJson(customMessage, Data::class.java)


                FileInputStream(file).use { fis ->
                    val buffer = ByteArray(chunkSize)
                    var bytesRead: Int
                    var chunkIndex = 0

                    while (fis.read(buffer).also { bytesRead = it } != -1) {
                        val chunk = buffer.copyOf(bytesRead)
                        val chunkBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(
                            chunk, Base64.NO_WRAP
                        ) // Encoding buffer to base64 string

                        val data = JSONObject().apply {
                            put("chunk", chunkBase64)
                            put("index", chunkIndex)
                            put("totalChunks", totalChunks)
                            put("fileName", file.name)
                            put("id", "2551")
                            put("reciver", reciver)
                        }

                        if (totalChunks-1==chunkIndex){
                            data.apply {
                                put("data",jsondta)
                            }

                        }
                            mSocket?.emit("file-chunk", data)
                        Log.e("TAG", "sendFile: $chunkIndex / $totalChunks", )


                        chunkIndex++
                    }
                }

            }.start()


        }

  fun sendFile1(filePath: String, reciver: String,chats: Chats) {
            val file = File(filePath)




            Thread {

                val customMessage = Data("live android", chats)
                val jsondta = json.toJson(customMessage, Data::class.java)

// fileName, reciver, data, fileBase64

                try {
                    val fileInputStream = FileInputStream(file)
                    val fileBytes = fileInputStream.readBytes()
                    val fileBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(fileBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP) // Encode the entire file to base64 string

                    val data = JSONObject().apply {
                        put("fileName", file.name)
                        put("reciver", reciver)
                        put("data", jsondta) // Add any additional data if required
                        put("fileData", fileBase64)

                    }

                    mSocket?.emit("file-chunk1", data)
                    Log.d("FileSender", "File sent: $filePath")

                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.e("FileSender", "Error reading or sending file", e)
                }


            }.start()


        }


    }

    init {
        try {
            mSocket = socket;
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.e(SocketIOService.TAG, "error: ${e.stackTrace}")
        }


    }

    fun listen(reciver: String?) {

        mSocket?.on(reciver) { args ->
            val chats: Data = Gson().fromJson(args[0].toString(), Data::class.java)

            try {
                SocketMessageHandeller.handleNewMessage(chats)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            try {
                val callback = args[args.lastIndex] as Any
                (callback as Ack).call("done")

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        };

        listnChunk("chunk_" + reciver)
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    fun listnChunk(reciver: String?) {

        mSocket?.on(reciver) { args ->
            try {
                val data = args[0] as JSONObject
                val fileName = data.getString("fileName")
                val fileData = data.getString("fileData")
                val msgdata = data.getString("data")
                val fileBytes = Base64.decode(fileData, Base64.DEFAULT)

                val file =
                    File(Constants.CATCH_DIR_Memory, fileName) // Specify the path to save the file
                if (file.exists()) {
                    file.delete()
                }
                try {
                    file.createNewFile()
                } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
                FileOutputStream(file).use { fos ->
                    fos.write(fileBytes)
                }



                Log.d("FileReceiver", "File received completely: ${file.absolutePath}")



                try {
                    val chats: Data = Gson().fromJson(msgdata, Data::class.java)
                    SocketMessageHandeller.handleNewMessage(chats)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }


                // Do something with the complete file
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }


}

I have made the changes in server Maxhttpbuffer to 100Mb. And also in client I have tried with sending the file with chunk of 1Mb and 5Mb still same issue persist. Help me please.
